# dashed line in Jfreechart

Tags: jfreechart

Does anybody knows how to draw a vertical dashed line in Jfreechart at some given coordinates ?

Thanks

Answer (score 23):

[Example 5](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartLineChartDemo5showingtheuseofacustomdrawingsupplier.htm) shows a series of dashed lines for a chart. Set your stroke thus:

```
plot.getRenderer().setSeriesStroke(
    0, 
    new BasicStroke(
        2.0f, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND, BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND,
        1.0f, new float[] {6.0f, 6.0f}, 0.0f
    )
```

and you'll need to set your dataset to simply reference the coordinates of your vertical line.

Comment: you could add );